# Angular 4 - Convert number to words

Tags: javascript, angular

My output `{{total.number}}` is in number format which is `1`. However, I want to convert that into `one`. I need it for 1-6 digits and the output be shown as  `one` - `six`.

How do I got about it? I see only JS examples but not the Angular method.

I got this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/ but I feel this is an overkill to achieve what I'm trying to do which is to convert the numbers 1 to 6 only.

Comment: The clean way in doing this is creating a Pipe for it. But it would be just as overkill. I don't think there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to define an array with your elements and `bind` input value to one variable, for instance, `ng-model="number"`.

As time as you typed into the `input` the value of the `number` is modified(`digest cicle` does this) and that mean you can display your desired output by passing the number as `index` for your `words` array.

```
<div id="word">{{words[number]}}</div>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.number=1;
  $scope.words= ['','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six'];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number" />
<div id="word">{{words[number]}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want it in AngularJS. Let me try if I can convert it into Angular. Don't know who downvoted you! I've upvoted it.

Comment: @ElaineByene, yes, in just few seconds i will post the updated answer.

Comment: @ElaineByene, have a look now.

Comment: Thank You but Angular 4 has stopped using $scope which is making my life hell :(
I don't know who edited out Angular 4 from my question!!

Comment: @ElaineByene, in angular 4 use `[(ngModel)]="number"`. `{{words[number]}}` remains the same.

Comment: And also declare your array in this follow: `public words= ['','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six'];` in the typescript file.

Answer (score 2):

Would use an object and access the desired value using bracket notation:

```
$scope.numbers = {
            0: 'zero',
            1: 'one',
            2: 'two',
            3: 'three',
            4: 'four',
            5: 'five',
            6: 'six'
        }

{{this.numbers[total.number]}}
```

You would be best to encapsulate the above logic into a pipe / filter

Comment: There's an error with `this` as "unexpected token". Thank you.

Comment: Whoops should be  $scope.

Comment: I'm working on AngularJS 4. $Scope isn't use anymore :(

Comment: I don't know who edited out Angular 4 from my question!!

Comment: @ElaineByene https://stackoverflow.com/users/6583140/alexandru-ionut-mihai edited your question. ;)